# spatio-temporal event prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning

i have a data that have some features like latitude , longitude , timestamp ,and category of an event . So the data set only has the events that actually took place . The thing is I am wondering if there is preferred models that can be used to predict the following cases :

- The place ( latitiude and longitude )of next event given the current
  timestamp.
- The high probable time event that  could occur given the current
  place.
- The probability of an event taking place given both time and space
  data.

Please note that i have looked for similar questions but they have different use case

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you asked, **random forest regressors** and **nearest neighbor regressors** are both general-purpose algorithms that have the potential to solve your problem and are a lot less finicky than techniques like neural networks.

**Update** I missed that one of your predictions was a probability. You really want probabilities to be calibrated correctly. You can either calibrate any regressive model after the fact, or you can start with models which emphasize correct probabilities. These will typically use a variant of **logistic loss**, and the most basic example thereof is [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Changing the metric in whichever technique you choose to "logloss" will be valuable.

One important point is to separate your data into "train" and "test" sets. This gives you a way of validating that your model generalizes as expected. Since you have time-varying data, **the test set should span the time after the train set for your time-based predictions**. This is different from generic approaches which would randomly select data points for each data set. Essentially, you want the difference between the test set and the train set to match as best as possible the difference between real-world data and the data you currently have observed.

That said, **the choice of algorithm doesn't really matter** anywhere near as much as a solid understanding of the data you're working with. Feature engineering should take the majority of your time. It is possible there is no information contained in your data, and [preliminary data visualizations](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) are probably going to be of great value to you.

Comment: very important information thanks,i ve did some research, first of all my data contains events that only occurred with its underlying features ,the thing is how to make probability prediction for a feature that doesn't exist as my data doesn't record the features of events that didnt take place.I have seen the proba_predict and uncertainity estimation functions that are made for binary and multiclass classification ,and i think it isnt preferred to create a feature of zero values for all the unmentioned time-series instances to make a binary class(occurred events -unoccured events)